# Can't solve the NullPointerException in my Calculator

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I am trying to create a calculator. I'm pretty new to the programing
and I got stuck with this NullPointerException.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at zavrsniirad.KonverzijeKalkulatora.<init>(KonverzijeKalkulatora.java:84)
    at zavrsniirad.DizajnKalkulatora.<init>(DizajnKalkulatora.java:28)
    at zavrsniirad.MainKalkulatora.main(MainKalkulatora.java:20)
```

The problem is that when I look at the place of the problem it leads me to the setting of the font

```
activeHEX.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
```

I know that NullPointException can be traced back or the variable is being set somwhere else.
That being said I can't find the solution.
This is the rest of the code

```
    private static JLabel MainDisplayFollower;

    
    private static JLabel passiveHEX;
    private static JLabel passiveOCT;
    private static JLabel passiveBIN;

    
    private static JLabel activeHEX;
    private static JLabel activeOCT;
    private static JLabel activeBIN;

    private String unos;

   
    Color bojaDispleja = new Color(212, 215, 223);
    Color bojaKaraktera = new Color(0, 0, 0);

    
    public KonverzijeKalkulatora() {

        MainDisplayFollower = new JLabel();
        MainDisplayFollower.setBackground(bojaDispleja);
        MainDisplayFollower.setForeground(bojaKaraktera);
        MainDisplayFollower.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.RIGHT);
        MainDisplayFollower.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        MainDisplayFollower.setBounds(5, 50, 395, 40);

        add(MainDisplayFollower);

        passiveHEX = new JLabel();
        passiveHEX.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        passiveHEX.setForeground(bojaKaraktera);
        passiveHEX.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        passiveHEX.setText("HEX");
        passiveHEX.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
        passiveHEX.setBounds(5, 140, 56, 30);

        add(passiveHEX);

        passiveOCT = new JLabel();
        passiveOCT.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        passiveOCT.setForeground(bojaKaraktera);
        passiveOCT.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        passiveOCT.setText("OCT");
        passiveOCT.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
        passiveOCT.setBounds(5, 175, 56, 30);

        add(passiveOCT);

        passiveBIN = new JLabel();
        passiveBIN.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        passiveBIN.setForeground(bojaKaraktera);
        passiveBIN.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        passiveBIN.setText("BIN");
        passiveBIN.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEtchedBorder(EtchedBorder.RAISED));
        passiveBIN.setBounds(5, 210, 56, 30);

        add(passiveBIN);

        activeHEX.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        activeHEX.setForeground(bojaKaraktera);
        activeHEX.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        activeHEX.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        activeHEX.setBounds(70, 140, 270, 30);

        add(activeHEX);

        activeOCT.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        activeOCT.setForeground(bojaKaraktera);
        activeOCT.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        activeOCT.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        activeOCT.setBounds(70, 175, 270, 30);

        add(activeOCT);

        activeBIN.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 14));
        activeBIN.setForeground(bojaKaraktera);
        activeBIN.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.LEFT);
        activeBIN.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        activeBIN.setBounds(70, 210, 270, 30);

        add(activeBIN);
```

If you could point me to the direction I should look to I would be grateful.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: I think you are missing activeHEX = new JLabel(); You need to do the same for activeOCT and activeBIN

Comment: Well that was a bit embarasing thank you

Comment: You should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase; class names in PascalCase.

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry I don't see where you create the object for **activeHEX**, probably you need to add

```
    activeHEX = new JLabel();
```

and as far as I see you are missing object creation for the next objects too.

If you don't assign a declared object, it has the default value *null*.

Comment: I didn't create activeHEX = new JLabel()  Solved my problem. Thank you